# Webgl - texture coordinates are offset

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm learning webGL and I've come across this problem, which I can't solve:

I'm making a simple tile game for practice and I'm using one image for all the textures. When I assign a certain vertex a texture coordinate it will sometimes have a little offset, which allows you to see part of other textures.

You can see an example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b7h7ena8/) (I've tilted the result so that the texture offset can be seen more easily)

The texture image is 64x64 and every tile is 8x8. The way I calculate each vertex's texture coords is this:

```
y0=1-(textp%8)/8;
y1=1-(textp%8+1)/8;
x0=Math.floor(textp/8)/8;
x1=Math.floor(textp/8+1)/8;
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the problem.
[image: le screenshot]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I am not sure I am seeing what you see. I see a beautiful game.

Comment: I've added a link to a screenshot (I don't have enough reputation to post an image...). You can see the problem best in the river. (and thank you)

Comment: Well, I don't see any of this in firefox or chrome.. is your browser zoomed?

Comment: No, and I've also tested it in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what it could be since it looks fine for me. You said it was **sometimes** without these lines and sometimes as in the screenshot, right? Can't you think of what you did differently when it worked?

Comment: What I mean by sometimes is that it depends on the angle and position of the objects. If it's not tilted I see the world perfectly, but if I move the character I can see the problem on their tiles too.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to reproduce your error. I don't understand what you mean by tilting, maybe that is not working for me and that's why I see a perfect visualisation.

Comment: I appreciate your help anyway! (by tilting I mean setting an angle so that the tiles are not perpendicular to the screen)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure of the perfect solution.

One would be to always use pixel coordinates. I'm guessing the problem is the tile you are trying to display is not on a perfect pixel boundary (like you scrolled your map 1.5 pixel down)?

[I solved it by not using texture coordinates for my tiles and doing all my tiling in the fragment shader](http://greggman.github.io/HappyFunTimes/public/examples/boomboom/gameview.html?settings=%7BhaveServer:false,numLocalPlayers:400,ai:true,waitForPlayersDuration:2,waitForStartDuration:2,bombStartSize:10,showFPS:true,showGithub:true%7D)

I guess since I have to post code on SO here's some code

vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 texcoord;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;
uniform mat4 u_texMatrix;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;
  v_texcoord = (u_texMatrix * texcoord).xy;
}
```

fragment shader

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_tilemap;
uniform sampler2D u_tiles;
uniform vec2 u_tilemapSize;
uniform vec2 u_tilesetSize;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  vec2 tilemapCoord = floor(v_texcoord);
  vec2 texcoord = fract(v_texcoord);
  vec2 tileFoo = fract((tilemapCoord + vec2(0.5, 0.5)) / u_tilemapSize);
  vec4 tile = floor(texture2D(u_tilemap, tileFoo) * 256.0);

  float flags = tile.w;
  float xflip = step(128.0, flags);
  flags = flags - xflip * 128.0;
  float yflip = step(64.0, flags);
  flags = flags - yflip * 64.0;
  float xySwap = step(32.0, flags);
  if (xflip > 0.0) {
    texcoord = vec2(1.0 - texcoord.x, texcoord.y);
  }
  if (yflip > 0.0) {
    texcoord = vec2(texcoord.x, 1.0 - texcoord.y);
  }
  if (xySwap > 0.0) {
    texcoord = texcoord.yx;
  }

  vec2 tileCoord = (tile.xy + texcoord) / u_tilesetSize;
  vec4 color = texture2D(u_tiles, tileCoord);
  if (color.a <= 0.1) {
    discard;
  }
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

The details of that technique [are here](http://blog.tojicode.com/2012/07/sprite-tile-maps-on-gpu.html) but the short version of it is it looks at a tile map in the shader to figure out what tiles to display.

[That code is here](https://github.com/greggman/hft-utils/blob/master/dist/tilemap.js) and in the same repo is code to load [Tiled maps](http://www.mapeditor.org/) that was mostly used in [this project](http://greggman.github.io/hft-tonde-iko).

Note: I ran into your same problem [trying to do with vertex texture coords](https://github.com/greggman/hft-utils/blob/master/dist/vertexbasedtilemap.js). Since doing it without them worked for me I didn't look into why it wasn't working. So I guess this isn't a direct answer to your question. I guess I'm hoping it's a solution though.